# Auto Renew Subscription RevenueCat Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, revenuecat

I Am using RevenueCat for my In-App purchases implementation for iOS. I have Purchasing a subscription working as well as Restoring purchases. When a user purchases the subscription they are given 2 full name reveals + many more things for an anonymous app. If a subscription is auto renewed while the user is not in the app. How will I be able to tell that the subscription is been renewed so I can reset their reveals if they have used it up.

Comment: The renewal transaction is presented to your transaction queue observer the next time they open the app. You can also use server side notifications

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the response when you say transaction queue observer are you talking about "purchases(_ purchases: Purchases, receivedUpdated customerInfo: CustomerInfo) " function in the "PurchasesDelegate" in the RevenueCat SDK

Comment: It looks like RevenueCat has documentation on subscription handling https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/customer-info